# Autocalculated fields in EF Core

Tags: .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-5.0

Using Ef5, I have the following class to persist

```
class Bar {
  decimal A { get; set; }
  decimal B { get; set; }

  decimal Max { get { return Math.Max(A, B); } }
  decimal? InvA { get { return A == 0 ? null : 1 / A; } } // this is 1/A
}
```

how should I manage this using EF Core? I try to do

```
class Bar {
  decimal A { get; set; }
  decimal B { get; set; }

  decimal Max { get; private set; }
  decimal? InvA { get; private set; }
}
```

in the config I do

```
builder.Property(p => p.Max).ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate();
builder.Property(p => p.InvA).ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate();
```

is it enough and correct?

Comment: you could make it a computed column: `.HasComputedColumnSql("1/[A] PERSISTED");`

Answer (score 0):

You can just annotate the corresponding properties with the DatabaseGenerated attribute:

```
public class Bar
{
    public decimal A { get; set; }
    public decimal B { get; set; }

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    public decimal Max { get { return Math.Max(A, B); } }

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    public decimal? InvA { get { return A == 0 ? null : 1 / A; } }
}
```

For more details, refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties?tabs=data-annotations#computed-columns).